# When and why did Slavs start counting their week from Monday?

Tags: calendar, time-keeping

In early middle ages it used to be normal to count Sunday as the first day of the week in the west Christian. In some countries it remained the case even today.

From what I was able able to dig up, Greece (the Eastern Roman Empire) was doing the same, at least in the religious calendar.

However, the Slavic names for the days of the week are named using ordinal numbers. And, notably, Tuesday [vъtorъkъ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/v%D1%8Ator%D1%8Ak%D1%8A) is literally "the second one", Wednesday [*serda](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/serda) is "the middle one", Thursday is "the fourth one" and Friday is "the fifth one".

The names can be traced back all the way to the mission of the saints Constantine and Methodius that brought christianity in the Slavic language (Latin missionaries were already active in the area) in the 9th century. Probably not much earlier as the names for Saturday, Sunday and Monday are clearly Christian.

What is the reason for this numbering? I assume it somehow comes from the Greek customs, but I cannot find any actual clue.

Or does it come from the west (Mittwoch)?

Comment: we do the same in the UK

Comment: Just pointing out that the Polish word for Monday (_poniedzałek_) literally means "after Sunday" (_po_ + loc. of _niedzela_ = _niedzelach_).

Comment: [Polish Wikipedia](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazwy_dni_tygodnia):  _"The names of the days of the week , as well as the week, in Polish , as in most Slavic languages, come from the early Christianization of the Slavs by missionaries in the 7th century, and the names of the days were created numerically "counting " their order after Sunday, which was originally the beginning of the week, but in common usage, these names have been taken as the number of the day of the week, with the result that Monday is considered the first day of the week"_

Comment: That sounds plausible. So the numbering would mean "second after Sunday", "fourth after Sunday"... with Sunday starting the religious week, but ordinary people reinterpretted as the number of the day of the week. Sreda ("the middle") would come later. I am surprised they date it all the way to the 7th century, but I am aware there were Latin missionaries active in the area well before the Greek mission.

Comment: They didn't; they simply used [exclusive (as opposed to inclusive) counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting#Inclusive_counting), starting from Sunday; unlike the Greeks who Christianized them, and who, like both Romans and Hebrews, employed [inclusive (as opposed to exclusive) counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting#Inclusive_counting), starting from the same (sun)day.

Comment: @Lucian That sounds like the sort of thing OP was looking for; you should post an answer.

Comment: Wednesday ("Sreda" - the middle day) would only have sense if the Wednesday is fourth day in the week (of 7 days) ;) Third day is not in the middle. Therefore, you see gradual evolution in the calendar.